# Displaying plotted AChartEngine graph in separate activity

Tags: android, button, android-linearlayout, achartengine

Initially trying to plot a graph using Google's [AChartEngine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/). However, I would like to plot it on a different layout with a back button. So far I can't find anything wrong with the code, but the graph isn't showing up when it needs to. So I have a main file which starts an intent to launch the ShowGraph activity. This code is working since it takes me to the appropriate screen. So the problem is that the graph doesn't show up in the linear layout, only the button does. Any suggestions or errors you can find?

```
buttonConfirm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    if (radioButtonGraph.isChecked()){
                        Intent sg = new Intent (MainActivity.this, ShowGraph.class);
                        startActivity(sg);

                    }
```

On the display graph screen, the xml looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >


   <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonBackGraph"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/coolbutton"
    android:text="@string/doneAlarm" >
    </Button>


    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/graphLayout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

The activity that uses this layout has a button, and a call to the graph function:

```
public class ShowGraph extends Activity{
Button buttonDone1;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.avgraph);
    buttonDone1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonBackGraph);
    buttonDone1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent dne = new Intent(ShowGraph.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(dne);
        }
    });
}

public void lineGraphHandler(View view){
    GraphActivity line = new GraphActivity();
    GraphicalView gView = line.getView(getApplicationContext());
    LinearLayout l1 = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.graphLayout);
    l1.addView(gView);
}

}
```

And finally, the graph function that renders the graph and supposed to plot in the linear layout above:

```
public class GraphActivity extends Activity {

public GraphicalView getView(Context context){
    //hardcoded plotting data for now
    int[]x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
    int[]y ={130, 150, 358, 200, 90,60, 110, 120, 130, 150};

    TimeSeries series = new TimeSeries ("BGL Data");
    for (int i=0; i<x.length;i++){
        series.add(x[i], y[i]);
    }

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mrenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    mrenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);
    mrenderer.setChartTitle("Blood Glucose Levels Tracking");
    mrenderer.setXTitle("Test Date and Time Reference Number"); //number corresponding to date and time of test
    mrenderer.setXAxisMin(0);
    mrenderer.setXAxisMax(10);
    mrenderer.setYTitle("Blood Glucose Level/ mg/dl");

    return ChartFactory.getLineChartView(context, dataset, mrenderer); 

}
}
```

Comment: It's not "Google's" AChartEngine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lineGraphHandler` method is not called anywhere.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. I added another button to the layout and set an onClick to reference the lineGraphHandler method.

Sorry i meant to say aChartEngine for Android